# Conditionally declare a state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I set up a state only if a certain prop provided? Something like this:

```
function Comp({scroll, children}) {
    const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (scroll) {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
            });
        }
    }, [])

  // Some other codes...

  return (
    // Some jsx
  );
}
```

I don't need the `scrollY` state and the side effect if no `scroll` prop provided. JavaScript does not allow declaration inside if condition and React does not allow useState inside if condition.

```
function Comp({ scroll, children }) {
    if (scroll) {
        const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
        useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
            });
        }, [])
    }

    // Some other codes...

    return (
        // Some jsx
    );
}
```

I am looking for something like this but obviously it won't work.

Comment: That seems like it would work. Does it not work?

Comment: @Nick I need all of these only if 'scroll' prop provided

Comment: I would do it pretty much how you've done it. If there's no scroll property, then don't use the `scrollY` value

Comment: You can't use any hooks in a condition. Rules of hooks !! https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:~:text=Don't%20call%20Hooks%20inside,each%20time%20a%20component%20renders.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Yes I know. So I have to declare it anyway no matter if it will be used?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. In your case, you need the state so you can track the scroll.

Comment: The only thing I would do is add `scroll` to the dependencies array to avoid stale state and remove the listener on unmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to React [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20call%20Hooks%20inside,each%20time%20a%20component%20renders.), dont use hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions, hook must be used only at top level. So for your question, there no conditional declaring state using `useState`

If you want implementing logic depending on specific prop, then you should implement it based on checking the prop, like the `useEffect` you did:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (scroll) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
       setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
      });
  }
}, [])
```

Or conditional rendering JSX:

```
{ scroll && renderStuffsIfScrollExist() }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too late for me to come up with the solution by myself.

Solve this by separating it to a custom hook:

```
const useScrollY = () => {
    const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            setScrollY(window.pageYOffset);
        });
    }, [])

    return scrollY;
}

function Comp({ scroll, children }) {
    const scrollY = scroll && useScrollY();
    // other codes
}
```